# How to get the filename of a required previous task output in Luigi

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

In the Luigi's samples I have read, when you want to use the output file of a previous required task you do something like this

```
@requires(TaskB)
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        with self.input().open('r') as input:
            input.read()...something else etc
```

so you are opening the output file from a previous required taskB automatically when you call `input`

However I want to do something different. I need the *complete file name* of that file. I don't need to open it yet, just the file name to pass it as an argument to some function.

How can I get the file name of the output of a previous task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your case the `self.input()` is a [LocalTarget](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.local_target.html?highlight=localtarget#luigi.local_target.LocalTarget).

You can Try `self.input().path` to get the path.

EDIT:

If `TaskB` defines multiple outputs, for example a list, you would have to do:

```
self.input()[0].path
```

Or you can iterate through it.
Having that said having multiple output is not [recommended](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#task-output)

If `TaskA` defines multiple inputs, the way to access the inputs is [explained here](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#task-input)

Comment: Thanks! I heard that sometimes the previous task `output` can give a list of files (instead on only one). Is that a possibility?